# Submitting from an ajax loaded form

Tags: jquery, html

H_i

Have anybody ideas for submitting ajax loaded form:
www.example.com/form.php is

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your name?</legend>
        <input type="name" id="name" />
        <button type="submit">OK!</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and www.example.com/index.php is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Myform</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="formDiv"></div>
        <button id="open">Open</button>
        <button id="close">Close</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#open').click(function() {
                        $('#formDiv').load('www.example.com/form.php');
                    });
                    $('#close').click(function() {
                        $('#formDiv').empty();
                    });
                    $('#formDiv form').submit(function() {
                        alert("Hello, "+($('#formDiv form #name').val())+"!");
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want that alerts an "Hello, myname" instead of a submit.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to set up an event handler for the dynamically loaded form:

```
$('#formDiv').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
    alert("Hello, "+($('#name').val())+"!");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

your forms submit event will not work because when it's executed, the form may not be loaded
Instead you should write the event on callback of load event like below

```
$('#formDiv').load('www.example.com/form.php',{},function() {
    $('#formDiv form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hello, "+($('#formDiv form #name').val())+"!");
    });
});
```

also in this case return false; will not work you need to use event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation using [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#formDiv').on('submit', 'form', function() {
    alert("Hello, "+($('#formDiv form #name').val())+"!");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('#formDiv form').live('submit',function() {
           alert("Hello, "+($('#formDiv form #name').val())+"!");
           return false;
    });
```

Comment: live is deprecated in latest jquery.

Comment: `live` is deprecated and should not be used any more.

Comment: Absolutely not. The `.live()` function was deprecated in 1.7, and has been removed entirely in 1.9.

Comment: @LokenMakwana It's not deprecated in the latest version of jQuery, it's been removed entirely.

Comment: I agree , `Live` is `deprecated` and removed from the latest version of jQuery , but stil i am using some older version of jQuery.